# public int Continue() : (Not all code paths return a value)

Tags: c#, return-type

I have written this function to use it into another class, but code generates an error and says,
**Not all code paths return a value.**
I also tried to search the solution regarding this problem and most of the answers were irrelevant to the actual problem.
Hoping to bump into the logical understanding for this kind of same errors.

```
using System;

namespace Practice
{
    class ContinueAgain
    {
        public int Continue()    //    (Not all code paths return a value)
        {
            rerun:
            try {

                char chAgain;

                //  user guiding message and then taking input
                Console.WriteLine("\nAgain? (y/n)\n");
                chAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                //  filtering the condition if the user wants to continue or not
                //  exiting out of the method if user selects 'Y'/'y'
                if (chAgain == 'y' || chAgain == 'Y')   //  if block begins
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                //  exiting out of the method if user selects 'N'/'n'
                else if (chAgain == 'n' || chAgain == 'N')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThank you for using :)\n");
                    return 0;
                }

                // printing user message if user enters any input apart from the asked input
                if(chAgain!='y' || chAgain!='Y' || chAgain!='n' || chAgain!='N')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThis input in invalid\n");
                    goto rerun;
                }
                #endregion if block 4 - ends
            }   //  try block ends

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would like to know what's causing or triggering this error event.

Comment: tip 1: ***do not*** use goto. just don't. ever. tip 2: go through your code line by line and think about what's happening. when an exception happens, you go to your catch-block, write a line, and end the method _without returning anything_

Comment: also: it seems what your method does is decide _whether or not_ something should happen. please use ***boolean*** for binary choices, not numeric datatypes. that's what booleans are made for.

Comment: You should completely review and improve this code and likely this will also fix your isse. As example, this if will always be true: if(chAgain!='y' || chAgain!='Y' || chAgain!='n' || chAgain!='N'). It seems you don't think about the difference between || and &&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value inside the `catch` block and at the end of the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 missing return statements in your code - after the last `if` statement and in the `catch` block